# Today's date in Access calendar control is disabled

Tags: ms-access, calendar

I have created a form in Access 2007 and have a text field and a calendar. The value from the calendar goes into the text field. I'm initialising the calendar by setting the default date in the form load event as below;

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

   Me!calDOB.Today

End Sub
```

It work fine and the calendar highlights the today's date when displayed, but if I tried to click on the highlighted date (5th) numeric block it it appears to be disabled and the calendar returns Empty as the value on the click event.

If I click on some other date (numeric block) then it returns the correct value.  I can then go back and select today's date.

Anyone know why this is happening?

[image: Calendar as it appears]

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are using the update event, rather than the click event for the control. An update will not occur because the control is not changed. You can select the click event in the code window and use than. In my version of the calendar control, today is the default and there is no need to set it.

Comment: The code is definitely on the click event.  But your answer had lead me to identifying the problem.  I'm assigning the empty value of the text field to the calender when it first loads up.  This makes the current date to be unselectable in the calendar. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

if you dont have to use your calendar, then i suggest to use this one http://allenbrowne.com/ser-51.html

its easy to use and it works fine

Comment: Good find, I think I'll use in my next project.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of your question on Active X Calendar Control 11.0 is:

`Private Sub Form_Load()`

Me![Calendar7].Value = Date

End Sub

-> Tested and Approved

Calendar7 is the "name" of your calendar when you clic on properties of your calendar.